# Upgrading from 12.04 to 13.10 and having problems

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I was unaware there was an up date was planning on asking about my up dating problems but I'm kind of lazy that. Way anyway I have red triangle with an Exclamation mark in side of it and if I click on it tells me that

```
The update information is outdated. This maybe caused by network problems or by a repository that is no longer available. Please update manually by clicking on this icon and then selecting 'check for updates' and check if some of the listed repositories fail."
```

I do so and get this from the update manager

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'd like to fix this as well as update to the newer version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal.
2. Type

   ```
   sudo software-properties-gtk
   ```
3. Press ENTER.
4. Uncheck EVERYTHING under the "Installable from CDROM/DVD" category.
5. Close that window and type this in terminal"

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
6. After that completes, type in terminal

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
7. Enjoy Ubuntu!

Edit: Made it simpler and faster.

Comment: Steps one through 3 brought me to the software centre so I looked up "Installable from CDROM/DVD" and brought me to Software Sources (software-properties-gtk) should I installant this?(and its vary late for me well early as its 1:43 am and thank you for the help

Comment: @nate1994a Try the edited steps.

Comment: OK now its telling me there are no updates.